# Condição com o teclado

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, python-2.7

Estou querendo fazer uma condição através das teclas que o usuário apertar. Por exemplo, se ele apertar 'ENTER' o script continua e se apertar 'ESC' o script para. Procurei na internet mas nao achei nada específico. Alguma sugestão de biblioteca?

ps: Estou programanndo em Python.

Comment: Você pode usar o biblioteca `keyboard` e definir eventos para cada tecla.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pynput import *
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.enter:
        _thread.start_new_thread(iniciar,())
    if key == Key.esc:
        exit()

with Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:   listener.join()
```